# Magento custom option with radio buttons on the same row

Tags: magento, radio-button

I've created a simple product with custom option for size (with radio buttons) instead of a configurable product. My problem is that radio buttons are displayed on different rows.

[see here](https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/700x402q90/674/1tiuqB.jpg)

I want my radio buttons to look more like [this](https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/578x349q90/661/gvnQL7.jpg)

What code should I edit? thank you in advance!

Comment: please provide your code.this is style sheet issue and need code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `float:left;` to stylesheet for `li`:

```
.product-options ul.options-list li {
  /*... yor style here ...*/
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: I have edited in styles.css (skin/frontend/default/default/css/styles.css) but it doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: i have .product-options ul.options-list li { line-height:1.5; padding:2px 0; float:left; }

Comment: are you sure that you are using this code? 1. It is from default/default magento theme. 2. With your code I get what you need without changing anything: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ycFtu.png

Comment: thank you, i edited styles for my current theme and now works. i have also added some 5px margin as the options were very crowded